# How to disable "Do you want to change the default write disk?" dialog

Tags: android, usb-otg

I have a Wiko Bloom running Android 4.4. When I connect a USB device via USB OTG, I get the following dialog:

```
External USB storage ready
Do you want to change the default write disk?
```

This dialog appears no matter if I change the default write disk to be USB or not; the next time I connect the USB device I get asked again.

I listen for UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED broadcasts in hopes that I could abort the broadcast and stop the broadcast from being passed on, but unfortunately this isn't an ordered broadcast.

Is there a way to prevent this dialog from appearing?

Comment: Ask Wiko. That is not a dialog common to all Android devices.